# Android Firebase: Hashmap can't be cast to a given Object type

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to query a firebase database to check if the user exists so, I can log them in. But, a strange issue has blocked me completely:

**Query Code**

```
String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
String password = emailEditText.getText().toString();

fbUsers.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).limitToFirst(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        HashMap<String, User> usersHashMap = (HashMap<String, User>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        Map.Entry<String, User> firstEntry = usersHashMap.entrySet().iterator().next();
        User foundUser = firstEntry.getValue();

        Log.d("Login: ", foundUser.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

**User Class**

```
public class User {
    private String email;
    private String password;

    User() {}

    public User(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

The strange issue is that the compiler says `ALL OK` but, in the runtime environment, this exception is thrown at `Log.d()`

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   com.example.project.User

Comment: What line do you get the error at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datasnapshot HashMap cannot be cast to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792494/datasnapshot-hashmap-cannot-be-cast-to-another-class)

Comment: This `HashMap<String, User> usersHashMap = (HashMap<String, User>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` probably should just be `User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);` based on the error.

Answer (score 2):

This code uses `getChildren().iterator().next()` to get a snapshot for the single query result.

```
fbUsers.orderByChild("email")
        .equalTo(email).limitToFirst(1)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> iter = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            User foundUser = iter.next().getValue(User.class);
            Log.d("Login: ", foundUser.getEmail());
        } else {
            Log.w("Login: ", "No match: " + email);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        if (databaseError != null) {
            Log.e("Login: ", "onCancelled: " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I found that when I was entering data in the Firebase Web UI for test purposes, I had entered a numeric password which Firebase assumed as `Long` not `String` so, `User` was not valid to be instantiated automatically. But, all of this should have been reported when I tried to cast the DataSnapshot to a `Hashmap<String, User>` but, it didn't. Made the issue worse. Although, there was no way for you to figure this out, can you put that in your answer so, I can accept it?

Comment: @RexOverflow: Are you saying your code worked after you corrected the numeric field in the DB?

Comment: Well, a code similar to yours worked after I modified the password field's value to String type otherwise, it was throwing an error `Could not convert Long to String`. I didn't test the original code after I made the change. I believe the problem with the original code was also because of the field type. I'll update here after I get to check the project again.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried calling getValue(User.class) ?

Comment: getValue() just reads the data from the JSON as primitive types i belive. The error tells that you are attempting to cast a bunch of primitives in a more complex Object (User.class) . What you want to use instead is  this one : 
getValue(Class<T> valueType)
This method is used to marshall the data contained in this snapshot into a class of your choosing.

Comment: Davide, the dataset returned by Firebase and its ability to be casted to a given Object type depends on how deep you're in the JSON tree while fetching data. As I was somewhat around where multiple records of User were being returned, I can't simply call `getValue(User.class)` and expect Java to be smart enough. When your data has string keys and multiple key-value pair against it, Firebase returns a `HashMap<String, Object>` and when we have numeric keys and multiple key-value pair then Firebase returns an `ArrayList<Object>`. Primitive types are handled accordingly.

Comment: Yeah what i usually do is just fetch the data iterating dataSnapshot.getChildren() and then using getValue(Class<T> valueType) in a for loop. I find it way cleaner than having to deal with HashMap